# Deallocating an object directly

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, garbage-collection, dealloc

I'm still learning objective-C and there is a rule, it's never to directly deallocate an object directly. I don't understand what that means.

Can someone give me an example of this rule being broken..

here is how it's supposed to be done.

CORRECT WAY

```
-(id)someMethod {
Class *object = [[Class alloc]init];
[object someMethod];
[object release];
}
```

The above is considered correct..

So what is the bad way? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

> never to deallocate an object directly

That means you should never send -dealloc message to an object directly - the only valid situation for that is sending dealloc to superclass in dealloc implementation:

```
- (void)dealloc{
   ...
   [super dealloc];
}
```

Note also that with ARC(Automatic reference counting) you should not call dealloc even in that case.

Answer (score 2):

> it's never to directly deallocate an object directly

That means that you should not call `deallocate` method of `object` directly:

```
-(void)someMethod {
    Class *object = [[Class alloc]init];
    [object someMethod];
    [object release];    // <- it is correct
    [object dealloc]; // <- error here!
}
```

Comment: I'll add that the method is incorrect, as it must return an id and doesn't return anything

Comment: Thanks so much :) 

To all three that replied, you're a big help. Now I understand.

Comment: Oh and yeah geoffroy, that's true, I wasn't paying attention to the return type.. it should be -(void) since nothings returned but I just wrote fast. :)

Answer (score 1):

The incorrect way would be to call `[object dealloc]` directly, which will destroy the object. It will be called by `release` once nobody is retaining it any more.